# Como chamar o onblur a partir desse submit?

Tags: javascript

```
$("#more").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    alert('estou aqui');
    var link = $("#link").val();
    var date = $("#date-foundation").val();

    var validation = true;

    if (link === null || link === '') {
        $("#link").addClass("input-required");
        validation = false;
    }

    if (validation === true) {
        $.ajax({
            url: './model/functions/link_repeat.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {link: link},
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                if (data === 'true') {
                    $("#link").addClass("input-required");
                    $("#alert-link").append("<span style='color:red'><b>Esse link já existe! Escolha outro!</b></span>");
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Olá Ana, podes explicar melhor o que queres dizer com _"chamar o `onblur` a partir desse submit"_? Tens algum auscultador de evento `blur` que queres acionar quando `submit`` ocorre, é isso?

Comment: Na verdade o onblur eu chamo atraves do nome da função né. E nesse caso quero colocar ele no meu input. Como colocar? onblur = ?

Comment: Então não podes simplesmente invocar a função antes do ajax? simplesmente com `minhaFuncao();` no código?

Comment: então mas nesse caso minha função não tem nome, como vc chamaria ela?

Comment: Hmmm... eu ainda não percebi. Podes explicar por passos o que queres que aconteça? Por exemplo: click no submit > aciona o submit da form e corre o codigo na pergunta > e depois?...

Comment: Então eu tenho um input aonde estou fazendo uma validação, quero que só valide se a pessoa alterar o que está escrito. Se a pessoa não mexer no input não é pra validar.

Comment: Ok, e qual é a logica para validar? como chamas essa logica? é através do `blur` quando clicas no botão `submit`?

Answer (score 0):

Talvez o conceito de onBlur não está claro. 
Confira no link para você entender melhor o evento gerado ao tirar o mouse sobre um objeto e o evento após você alterar o valor de um elemento ([onBlur x onChange em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785099/what-is-the-difference-between-onblur-and-onchange-attribute-in-html))

Veja se o que você precisa é isso em seu arquivo javascript

```
var inputsAlterados = 0;

$('.classeParainputs').change(function () {
    inputsAlterados++;
});

$("#botaoGravar").submit(function () {
    if (inputsAlterados > 0) {
        /**
            Continuidade da lógica para salvar
        **/
    }
});
```